# Using stack behind proxy

Tags: pem, haskell-stack

I work behind a proxy that uses a `.pem` certificate. How would I create a global configuration for stack to use? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently supported.  I've opened this issue to track a discussion of the feature https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1922

I think we'd really rather rely on the OS's support for certs / proxies.  Is that not working out?

Comment: The super user of my system prefers to leave that to users. Simple as that. I decline to discuss their reasons. ;7)